# Drawing line with lon, lat, distance and azimuth?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, sld, line, direction

I have table in PostGIS with **lon**, **lat**, **distance** and **azimuth** columns.
I want to make Geoserver draw a line through first point with given length and direction. I can turn **lon** and **lat** to geometry in PostGIS with *ST_MakePoint* command.

Is it possible to draw line using only SLD with first point and attribute values or do I need to calculate second point manually and turn it to geometry too?

Comment: SLD is exclusively for styling, so you will need to make the other point, yes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've got an idea that SLD can do something like [this](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-extensions/rendering-transform.html). May be, there is some code, that can draw line with length, depending on attrubute value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [GeoServer SQL view](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html) feature, and SQL's [ST_Project](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Project.html) like,

```
SELECT id, 
  ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeLine(
    ST_MakePoint(lon,lat),
    ST_Project(
       ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon,lat),4326)::geography, 
       distance, 
       pi()*azimuth/180.0)::geometry
  ),4326) AS geom
FROM mytable;
```

If you have long lines and want to plot them as great circles on a flat map, you might want to densify them with [ST_Segmentize](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Segmentize.html) in geographic space to show them as great circles.

```
SELECT id, 
  ST_Segmentize(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeLine(
    ST_MakePoint(lon,lat),
    ST_Project(
       ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon,lat),4326)::geography, 
       distance, 
       pi()*azimuth/180.0)::geometry
  ),4326)::geography,100000)::geometry AS geom
FROM mytable;
```

**Added**

```
SELECT id, 
  ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeLine(
    ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon,lat),4326),
    ST_Project(
       ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon,lat),4326)::geography, 
       distance, 
       pi()*azimuth/180.0)::geometry
  ),4326) AS geom
FROM mytable
```

Comment: thank you very much, this is exactly what I need. I've added to your answer my version of SQL statement that work for me.