# Create line feature from point feature attributes: azimuth and distance

Tags: pyqgis, point, line

I've used Shape Tools plugin's Azimuth Distance Digitizer tool, to point and click, and then enter azimuth and distance in order to get a line.

This case is the same, but I have many features, so it would be nice an automated way to create these line features.

I've read [Draw line with lon, lat, distance and azimuth](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151763)

Can someone point me in the right direction to make it with QGIS?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: Yes! Thanks. Indeed, I'm writing some pyqgis code, and when done I'll share it here.
As to the research, sure I've done that, but my question is so simple that I prefer not to bother with the details, since that research conduced me to ask that (plugin, way, script, tool) that I couldn't find.

Comment: For a better understanding: you want to select a few points and then you want to create line features (with azimuth and length) for this selection? Or do you have point attributes which are holding information about azimuth and distance?

Comment: See also: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/258950/programatically-add-polylines-from-existing-points-in-qgis. Especially: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/259542

Answer (score 1):

I have answered a question similar to this previously which uses the python console.

See the full answer over here:
**[How to depict line symbols with length from attribute](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/208185/how-to-depict-line-symbols-with-length-from-attribute/227501#227501)**

Taking an input file (with start location, length, and Azimuth data) the final output looks like:

[image: example output]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know which pyqgis function corresponds to your qgis tool, here is the way :

Run the tool with appropriated parameters once in QGIS.

Go in Geoprocessing > History

You will find the right way to use it with pyqgis.

Good luck !